# how to solve Asyncstorage multiset not storing any data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, asyncstorage

good day everyone,

i'm working on a react-native project where i use AsyncStorage to save some of my data that doesn't require the presence of a fully fledged database.
in this regard i have faced some problems using this feature, mainly the multiset static method of the AsyncStorage.
i use multiset inside a redux action but for some reason it doesn't work despite the action being called properly, and the weirder part about this is that it worked with another action.

this is the action that works:

```
export const saveChosenCompany = (username, company) => dispatch => {
    AsyncStorage.multiSet([
        [`${username}.companyID`, company.id],
        [`${username}.companyName`, company.name]
    ])
    .then(() => {
        dispatch({
            type: SAVED_COMPANY,
            payload: company
        })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        dispatch({
            type: SAVED_COMPANY,
            payload: {
                id: null,
                name: null
            }
        })
    })   
}
```

this is the action that doesn't work properly:

```
export const saveConfigs = (configs) => dispatch => {
    console.log("action", configs)
    AsyncStorage.multiSet([
        [`updateStockpile`, configs.stockpile],
        [`updateData`, configs.data],
        [`emptyPhone`, configs.emptyPhone],
        [`language`, configs.language],
        [`autoUpdate`, configs.autoUpdate],
    ])
    .then(() => {
        console.log("set async...")
        dispatch({
            type: SAVE_CONFIG,
            payload: configs
        })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log('no async set...')
    })
}
```

this is the way i'm implementing it inside my component:

```
saveChangedConfigs = async () => {
        this.props.saveConfigs({
            stockpile: this.state.updateItem.toString(),
            data: this.state.updateData.toString(),
            delete: this.state.emptyFiles.toString(),
            autoUpdate: this.state.autoUpdate,
            language: this.state.language
        })
    }
```

i call this method from within the onChange prop of the native picker, native switch and the react-native-numeric-input custom component from the library with the same name.

i hope some here help me figure out why the multiset is not working ( i tested it by getting the values and they were all null).

thanks everyone in advance for your time and trouble.

Comment: Do you get something in the console?

Comment: try using `async`/`await` in `AsyncStorage.multiSet`

Comment: How are you calling `saveChosenCompany` (which works)?

Comment: @Vencovsky i get the console.log that executes before the multiset and can't use async await inside a redux actions because redux doesn't support it or at least that's what i got as an error when i tried it

Comment: @Dan i use it inside the picker onValueChange method by just calling this.saveChosenCompany()

Answer (score 0):

apparently the problem was with the virtual machine or something because it just started working without me doing anything. sounds weird and it is weird but that's what happened.